# Cross AWS account Code Pipeline deployment confusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am going to set up the following, but some concepts are not clear to me:

AWS Account A with code pipeline setup, AWS ECR and code build to run K8s commands and deploy into AWS Account B EKS cluster.

Some details in the setup which I am unsure:

- I understand assume role is required to do the deployment from Account A in this case?
  What other permissions is required?
- Do we need to do VPC peering or equivalent to allow AWS code build to have
  access to the K8s cluster in Account B?
- Do we need to setup any connectivity to AWS ECR for Account B to pull the images when K8s commands are executed via code build in Account A?

Many thanks